# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix' is the error i am getting

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a2149c60e478> in <module>
      4 from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
      5 df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\sandy\data\cairns-nov2019-data_2.csv")
----> 6 coords = df.as_matrix(columns=['Latitude','Longitude'])

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as\_matrix' in jupyter notebook](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/68653/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-as-matrix-in-jupyter-noteb)

Comment: @Sammy Page not found

Answer (score 1):

Change that line to:

```
coords = df[["Latitude", "Longitude"]].values
```

Comment: It's gonna be depracated. Pandas recommend to use `to_numpy` instead. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy